# New Apple Sign In conflicts with Google Login, generates 2 user accounts

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, apple-sign-in

I'm having a problem where users previously signed up either through Google sign-in or email on my app cannot sign in to the same account with Apple Sign In (even with the email not hidden).

Even though auth tokens are handled separately, Apple and Google/Firebase, the same email in our Users Collection cannot be merged (keep existing user account and use new token for the existing account). This results in 2 accounts: existing and new which is problematic with the new Apple Sign In.

Has anyone run into this problem for their iOS app, and with the upcoming spring Apple Sign In requirement, how are they handling 2 tokens and merging new and old accounts?

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import Pages
import GoogleSignIn
import AuthenticationServices

class FireAuthUserInfo {
    var firstName:String?
    var lastName:String?
    var email:String?

    init(googleUser:GIDGoogleUser) {
        self.firstName = googleUser.profile.givenName
        self.lastName = googleUser.profile.familyName
    }
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    init(credential:ASAuthorizationCredential) {
        switch credential {
                  case let appleIDCredential as ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential:

                  default:
                      break
                  }
    }

}
class UserManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = UserManager()

    func signInWithGoogle (user: GIDGoogleUser) {
        let authentication = user.authentication
        let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: (authentication?.idToken)!,
                                                       accessToken: (authentication?.accessToken)!)
        let userInfo = FireAuthUserInfo(googleUser: user)
        self.authInFirebase(with: credential, user: userInfo)
    }
    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    func signInWithApple (with credential:AuthCredential, appleUser:ASAuthorizationCredential) {
        let userInfo = FireAuthUserInfo(credential: appleUser)
        self.authInFirebase(with: credential, user: userInfo)
    }
    func authInFirebase(with credential:AuthCredential, user:FireAuthUserInfo? = nil) {
        Utility.showProgress("")
        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (authResult, error) in
            guard error == nil else { Utility.dismissProgress(); return}
            guard let authResult = authResult else { Utility.dismissProgress(); return}

            // User is signed in
            let refCollection = Constants.db.databaseProfile

            var query = refCollection.whereField("UserID", isEqualTo: authResult.user.uid)
            if let user = user, let email = user.email {
                query =  refCollection.whereField("email", isEqualTo: email)
            }
            query.getDocuments(completion: { (snapShot, error) in
                Utility.dismissProgress()
                guard error == nil else { return}
                if snapShot == nil || snapShot!.isEmpty == true {
                    let userObject = User()
                    userObject.uid = authResult.user.uid
                    userObject.email = authResult.user.email

                    if let user = user {
                        userObject.firstName = user.firstName
                        userObject.lastName = user.lastName
                        if let email = user.email {
                            userObject.email = email
                        }
                    }

                    self.saveProfile(user: userObject)
                    //self.gotoFillDetails(page: 3)
                    self.goToOnBoardingScreens()
                }else {
                    for rest in snapShot!.documents {
                        let restDict = rest.data()
                        guard !(restDict.isEmpty) else {
                            continue
                        }
                        let userData = User.getInstanceFrom(dictionary: restDict)!
                        if let user = user, let email = user.email {
                            userData.email = email
                        }
                        UserDefaultHelper.saveUser(user: userData)
                        AppData.sharedInstance.user = userData
                        AppData.getAllJournalEntries()
                        break
                    }
                    self.gotoMain()
                }

            })
        }
    }

    func saveProfile(user : User) {
        let autoKey = User.getNewKey()
        //        let autoKey = Constants.refs.databaseProfile.childByAutoId().key
        let newProfile = [
            "UserID": user.uid ?? "",
            "Email": user.email ?? "",
            "FirstName": user.firstName ?? "",
            "LastName": user.lastName ?? "",
            "Gender": "",
            "BirthDate": Date(),
            "JobTitle": "",
            "Location": "",
            "TellMeMore": "",
            "Referral": "",
            "Last_Login": Date(),
            "CreatedAt": Date(),
            "UpdatedAt": Date(),
            "ProfileImage": "",
            "Key": autoKey,
            "DeviceToken": AppData.sharedInstance.deviceToken ?? "",
            "FcmToken": AppData.sharedInstance.fcmToken ?? "",
            ] as [String : Any]

        let user = User.getInstanceFrom(dictionary: newProfile)
        user?.saveToFirebase()
        UserDefaultHelper.saveUser(user: user!)
        AppData.sharedInstance.user = user
    }
```

I've been able to reproduce these results in the Apple test app: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple. When a user signs in with Apple and shares her email address at that time, I'm able to receive user's email, but when the user tries to log in again, I'm not able to receive that email. Seems like an Apple oversight?

Comment: You need to show your code.

Comment: updated, thanks @Magnas

Comment: Are you using the "multiple accounts per email" setting in your Firebase project? That will result in multiple accounts being created each time the user signs in with a different provider, even though the emails are the same.

Comment: No, I haven’t changed the default @bojeil. The default is one account per email address.